Google Drive API Returns 200 (HTTP Success) for testing pdf export but no file
The entire test script is as follows:
// File export test: Authorization code: https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/76bef3ab760f335d43eccaf481e0b4d0 
// Google Ref https://github.com/googleworkspace/node-samples/blob/main/drive/snippets/drive_v3/file_snippets/export_pdf.js

const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
// File id of the file to download = ocrTransfer folder in My Drive
const FILEID = '1_h-GsdKAqmu0hmZAmGslfqvE7W9ppMlt2WNGhi9diYk';

// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'DownloadFileToken.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\googleDriveDev\\credentials.json';

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fsp.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fsp.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fsp.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}


/**
 * Download a Document file in PDF format
 * @param{string} fileId file ID
 * @return{obj} file status
 * */

async function exportPdf(authClient) {
  
  const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});

  try {
    
    const result = await service.files.export({
      fileId: FILEID,
      mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    });
    console.log(result.status);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO(developer) - Handle error
    throw err;
  }
}

authorize().then(exportPdf).catch(console.error);

Output:
C:\googleDriveDev>node ./exportTest1.js
200

Why does this return indicate success but the file does not download?
I am using GDOC files by getting the ID from the URL. To me the script should do the same as:
Open document in Google Drive> Choose File> Download > PDF Document (.pdf)
In the past have been able to export gdocs as plain text files. But that option no longer works so I am trying another approach.

“Why does this return indicate success but the file does not download?” Can you point to which specific line or lines in this code you feel should download or store the contents of the resulting file somewhere? If you’ve implemented this, I’m not seeing where.

Good point. I should have asked myself that same question.

I thought variables of type const (constant) are declared at the head of the code. And are 'set' for the duration of the code run? I'm thinking of C languages. Just a point of confusion. Re: const result = await service.files.export()

Modification points:
About your question of Why does this return indicate success but the file does not download?, when I saw your showing script, result of const result = await service.files.export({,,,}) in the function exportPdf is not used. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to save the exported data as a file, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
In your showing script, please modify it as follows.
From:
async function exportPdf(authClient) {
  
  const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});

  try {
    
    const result = await service.files.export({
      fileId: FILEID,
      mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    });
    console.log(result.status);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO(developer) - Handle error
    throw err;
  }
}

authorize().then(exportPdf).catch(console.error);

To:
async function exportPdf(authClient) {
  const service = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth: authClient });

  try {
    const result = await service.files.export(
      {
        fileId: FILEID,
        mimeType: "application/pdf",
      },
      { responseType: "stream" } // Added
    );
    console.log(result.status);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO(developer) - Handle error
    throw err;
  }
}

authorize()
  .then(exportPdf)
  .then(({ data }) => { // Added
    const destFile = fs.createWriteStream("sample.pdf"); // Please set the path and the output filename.
    data
      .on("end", function () {
        console.log("Done.");
      })
      .on("error", function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return process.exit();
      })
      .pipe(destFile);
  })
  .catch(console.error);

When this modified script was run, I confirmed that the file of FILEID could be correctly exported and the exported file could be saved as a file.
Note:

From the length of FILEID in your showing script, I guessed that the file of FILEID might be a Google Docs file (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides, and so on). In this case, the export method can be used. But, if you want to download the files except for Google Docs files, please use the get method instead of the export method. Please be careful about this. I thought that this thread might be useful for understanding it. Ref


Thank you. I am converting gdocs to plain text. So Export is what I want to use.

@Dave Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In the case of conversion from Google Document to the plain text, the export method can be used.
